# Use DateFormat.SHORT in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to format an `Instant` using a predefined format of Java. I can do this in Java:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, request.getLocale());
// this will hopefully format a Date to 12.09.2018 02:10
```

And I want this to be done in Thymeleaf using my `Instant` type:

```
<div th:text="${#temporals.format(work.indexTime)}"></div>
<!-- this will print "2018-09-12T02:10:06Z" -->
```

But how can I tell Thymeleaf to use the `DateFormat.SHORT` settings?

EDIT:

My current workaround is this:

Controller:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
        .withLocale(request.getLocale())
        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Template:

```
<div th:text="${dateFormatter.format(work.indexTime)}"></div>
```

Comment: Are you using [thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time)? If so, there's a pretty clear example using a format string, eg `${#temporals.format(temporal, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')}`

Comment: I want to use a format provided by Java - specific to my locale. It's a multi language project I'm working on. So a static format pattern is not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify `SHORT` as the format.

```xml
<div th:text="${#temporals.format(work.indexTime, 'SHORT')}"></div>
```

From [the README](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time#readme):

> ```
> /*
>  * Format date with the specified pattern
>  * SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG and FULL can also be specified to used the default java.time.format.FormatStyle patterns
>  * Also works with arrays, lists or sets
>  */
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can set that up in thymeleaf, but it's pretty verbose... this works for me:

```
<th:block th:with="clazz=${T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)},
          style=${T(java.time.format.FormatStyle).SHORT},
          zone=${T(java.time.ZoneId).systemDefault()},
          formatter=${clazz.ofLocalizedDateTime(style).withLocale(#locale).withZone(zone)}">
    <span th:text="${formatter.format(work.indexTime)}" />
</th:block>
```

You could also add a default converter from Instant to String and use the double bracket syntax when outputting an Instant:

Context:

```
public class Context extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry r) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                .withLocale(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
                .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        r.addConverter(new Converter<Instant, String>() {
            @Override
            public String convert(Instant s) {
                return s != null ? dateFormatter.format(s) : "";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div th:text="${{work.indexTime}}" />
```